# Creating an Iterative - Javascipt

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, iteration

I have a recursive function below and I was just wondering how can I create an iterative (i.e. loops without recursion) for the same thing. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions thank you!

```
function countPalindromes(string, count) {
  if (string.length <= 1) {
    return count;
  }

  let [ firstLetter ] = string;
  let lastLetter = string[string.length - 1];

  if (firstLetter === lastLetter) {
    let stringWithoutFirstAndLastLetters = string.substring(1, string.length - 1);
    return countPalindromes(stringWithoutFirstAndLastLetters, count + 1);
  } else {
    return count;
  }
}

console.log(countPalindromes("level", 0));
console.log(countPalindromes("aya", 0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while, but this should work.

```js
function countPalindromes(string, count) {
  for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(string.length/2); i++) {
    if (string.charAt(i) === string.charAt(string.length - i-1)) {count++};
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countPalindromes("level", 0));
console.log(countPalindromes("aya", 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function countPalindromes(string) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(string.length / 2); i++) {
    const letterFromTheStart = string[i];
    const letterFromTheEnd = string[(string.length - 1) - i];
    if (letterFromTheStart !== letterFromTheEnd) {
      break;
    }
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countPalindromes("level"));
console.log(countPalindromes("aya"));
```

The important parts are `i < Math.floor(string.length / 2)` and `(string.length - 1) - i`.

The first one assures the loop stops before or at the half of the string and the second gets the `n`th character starting from the string's end.

Comment: @28space_junkiee Yes, the `for` loop makes it iterative.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the string and compare letters until you hit a mismatch returning the last index that matched plus one.

```js
function isPalindrome(word) {
  const drow = word.split('').reverse();
  
  for (i = 0; i < drow.length && drow[i] === word[i]; i++);
  
  return i;
}

console.log(isPalindrome("level"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your recursive palindrome function. Just converted the recursive one to iterative one.

```
 function countPalindromes(string, count) {
        if (string.length <= 1) {
            return count;
        }
        let i = 0, j = string.length-1;
        for (; i < j && string[i] == string[j]; i++, j--);
        return i;
    }
    
    console.log(countPalindromes("level", 0));
    console.log(countPalindromes("aya", 0));
```